# Eval'd behind the scene?

Tags: javascript, function, eval

I heard that when I'm doing this:

```
<a onclick='foo()'></a>
```

behind the scenes, it generates me an anonymous function, or maybe an eval'd function...? I'm confused, because I do have a function `foo`, so where is the extra code?

Could I please get some explanation/clarification ?

Comment: Is your function named `foo` or `Foo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does. It generates an anonymous function, which has body set to what you've enclosed in quotes (so it will call your `foo()` when executed).

It can be observed when you put a breakpoint in your function and look at the stack trace when it gets hit.

**Update**

Some illustations: [Firebug/Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html) ([more Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript)), [Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.html)

Comment: I saw this behind : 

    function onclick(event) {
    foo();
    }
but how does he knows that it belongs to the a.click and not div.click ?? where is matching ? I couldnt find it.

Comment: It's stored internally. You cannot see this in the debugging tools. Chrome however offers an "Event Listeners" tab in the [Elements Panel](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/chrome/devtools/docs/elements.html) where you can see all listeners on a certain element.

Comment: The browser knows where it belongs because that's its job. What you see is a convenient, human-readable representation of a definition of an inline function. And you know where it belongs because it shares that knowledge with the user ;)